# Constraint Violated in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, check-constraints

I created the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE SALES_ORDER2_56 (
    ORDERNO VARCHAR2 (6) CONSTRAINT SOpkey1 PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT SOcheck1 CHECK (ORDERNO LIKE 'O%'),
    CLIENTNO VARCHAR2 (6) CONSTRAINT SOfkey1 REFERENCES CLIENT_MASTER2_56 (CLIENTNO),
    ORDERDATE DATE CONSTRAINT SOnull1 NOT NULL,
    DELYADDR VARCHAR2 (25),
    SALESMANNO VARCHAR2 (6) CONSTRAINT SOfkey2 REFERENCES SALESMAN_MASTER2_56 (SALESMANNO),
    DELYTYPE CHAR (1) DEFAULT 'F',
    CONSTRAINT SOcheck2 CHECK (
        DELYTYPE LIKE 'F'
        OR DELYTYPE LIKE 'P'
    ),
    BILLYN CHAR (1),
    DELYDATE DATE,
    ORDERSTATUS VARCHAR2 (10),
    CHECK (
        ORDERSTATUS IN (
            'In Process',
            'Fulfilled',
            'BackOrder',
            'Cancelled'
        )
    ),
    CONSTRAINT SOcheck3 CHECK (DELYDATE > ORDERDATE)
);
```

But whenever I try to run this :

```
INSERT INTO SALES_ORDER2_56 (ORDERNO,CLIENTNO,ORDERDATE,SALESMANNO,DELYTYPE,BILLYN,DELYDATE,ORDERSTATUS)
    VALUES('O19001','C00001','12-jun-04','S00001','F','N','20-jul-04','In Process');
```

It gives me this: **[Err] ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SOFKEY2) violated - parent key not found**

I tried many times but in vain. Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This answer was in response to the original version of the question,
>   it has since been edited which makes the answer seem irrelevant.

The `CHECK`constraint for `ORDERSTATUS`demands that `ORDERSTATUS` is one of either`In Progress`, `Fulfilled`, `BackOrder` or `Cancelled`, but in your insert query you use `In Process` which violates the constraint. I'm guessing you meant to use `In Progress`?

---

The error `[Err] ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SOFKEY2) violated - parent key not found`

indicates that the SALESMANNO S00001 doesn't exist in the SALESMAN_MASTER2_56 table

Comment: Ok sorry that was a typing mistake. So now it is saying this:

[Err] ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SOFKEY2) violated - parent key not found

Comment: Thanx I have solved it. Didn't insert any values in the referenced table. But, Thanx for correcting me.